# org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: Document is empty (something might be wrong with your XSLT stylesheet)

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Am trying to convert JSON into PDF document using Apache FOP. Please find my java code below, that am using to generate PDF document.

```
public class XML_XSLFOtoPDF {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    private static XML_XSLFOtoPDF instance = new XML_XSLFOtoPDF();

    public static XML_XSLFOtoPDF getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public String getPDF(JSONObject obj) throws IOException, DocumentException, TransformerException, FOPException, TransformerFactoryConfigurationError {

        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        String orderAcknowledgementTemplate = classLoader
                .getResource("resoources/sample2.xsl").getFile();
        String xslPath = orderAcknowledgementTemplate.replaceAll("%20", " ");
        File xsltfile = new File(xslPath);


        StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
        String header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(header);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(obj.toString());

        xml.append(header);
        xml.append("\n");
        xml.append("<receipt>");
        xml.append(XML.toString(json));
        xml.append("</receipt>");

        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml.toString()));   

        System.out.println("XML --->"+xml.toString());

        StreamSource transformSource = new StreamSource(xsltfile);
        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());
        FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Transformer xslfoTransformer;
        try
        {
            xslfoTransformer = getTransformer(transformSource);
                Fop fop;
            try
            {
                fop = fopFactory.newFop
                    (MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, outStream);

                        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

                try
                {
                    xslfoTransformer.transform(source, res); 
                    File pdffile = new File("Result.pdf");
                    OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdffile);  // Error is throwing on this line
                                out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);
                                FileOutputStream str = new FileOutputStream(pdffile);
                                str.write(outStream.toByteArray());
                                str.close();
                                out.close();

                }
                catch (TransformerException e) {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
            catch (FOPException e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        catch (TransformerConfigurationException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        return xslPath;
    }

    private static Transformer getTransformer(StreamSource streamSource)
    {
        net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl impl = 
                new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();

        try {
            return impl.newTransformer(streamSource);

        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Am getting the below error while am invoking method to generate PDF.

> org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: Document is empty (something might be wrong with your XSLT stylesheet).

for the below lines:

```
xslfoTransformer.transform(source, res);
OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdffile);
```

This is my XSL file with the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
        exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-height="8.5in" page-width="11in">
                    <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block>
                        Hello, <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                    !</fo:block>
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:table>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="75mm"/>

                            <fo:table-header>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        No.
                                        karthkeyan
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black"  text-align="center" font-weight="bold" width="60mm">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        Name
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        Phone Number
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-header>

                            <fo:table-body>
                                <xsl:for-each select="./friend">
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                                            <fo:block>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                                            <fo:block>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                                            <fo:block>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="phNo" />
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tested your XSLT file and it compiles ok. But with an empty XML file there's nothing to transform. So the error must be in your Java code, hence I changed one tag to 'Java'.

Comment: Am inject XML in the below like, `StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml.toString()));` . Actually am having JSONObjects and am converting into XML and giving to `StreamSource`  am unsure this is correct or not..

Comment: Show us the output of `System.out.println("XML --->"+xml.toString());` to enable us to tell how your XML looks and whether the XSLT makes any sense (i.e. whether the XML has elements like `root` or `friend` or `name`).

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Thanks you comments really helpful to me and i figured out the issue. It is because of `<xsl:template match="root">` this line in XSL.

Comment: I have to return the PDF document as `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of `FileOutputStream` i have raised a separate question for that `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206414/return-as-bytearrayoutputstream-instead-of-fileoutputstream-pdf-generation-fro`